# Terraform create list of resources

Tags: terraform

I am building a resource using terraform provider and would like to get some help. I am trying to create a resource of users from user0001 to user0500 (not user1 to user500). I am also generating a unique password for each users using count.

This is the code I have so far which works provided I manually add the users in the variable list. Doing this for 500 users is not feasible.

```
variable "list_of_users" {
  default = ["user0001","user0002","user0003"]
}

resource "random_string" "password" {
  count            = 3
  length           = 14
  special          = true
  override_special = "/@£$"
}

resource "user" "admin" {
  provider = "modules/main.tf"
  for_each = zipmap(var.list_of_users, random_string.password)

  userid    = each.key
  password  = each.value.result
  status    = "active"
}
```

I am not sure what could be the alternative to generate the desired user names instead of listing them all like this, `default = ["user0001","user0002","user0003"]` for 500 users. Please let me know if there are any methods or ways to do this in terraform.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it is possible to generate this list with a `for` expression inside a list constructor, using the `range` to establish the number of users, and using the `format` function to format the string as desired:

We first need to use `range` to establish an enumerable that is from 1 to 500. We then use `format` to format a string prefixed with `user`, and then a string representation of a number with default width and precision 4. These are used within the `for` expression within the `list` constructor to achieve the desired end result:

```
[for index in range(1, 501) : format("user%.4d", index)]
```

This list can then be assigned to a local variable or directly to a parameter for further use.

Comment: Matt, this is exactly what I needed, I was able to use the above function in a local variable and pass it to the resource block. Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: @Rob Glad it answered your question; please accept and upvote for posterity.